# How to remove multiple sub domain in google analytics tracking like beta.abc.combeta.abc.com/profile

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I set up cross domain set up as per documentation given https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

But in analytics view coming as "beta.abc.combeta.abc.com/profile" as URL in page view and URL.

I need output should be "beta.abc.com/profile"

Expected : I need output should be "beta.abc.com/profile"

Actual : "beta.abc.combeta.abc.com/profile"[image]

Comment: Looks like you've messed up your implementation. Provide your code so we can debug.

Comment: Is there a view filter set up to put host in the page URI variable? Host is not part of pagePath by default.

Comment: any help in this ?